# pass single value from viewbag in mvc4 to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
      `  // javascript 
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([

          ['I', 1],
          ['D', 2],
          ['S', 3],
          ['Sh', 4],

        ]);`
```

I need to pass these value instead of the numbers above :

```
<%: ViewBag.QuerySh %></div> <%: ViewBag.QueryI %></div> <%: ViewBag.QueryS %></div>
<%: ViewBag.QueryD %></div>
```

Bytheway, the value in the view page holding integers

Please any idea ??? !!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your javascript is inline, you can do:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
data.addRows([
  ['I', <%: ViewBag.QueryI %>],
  ['D', <%: ViewBag.QueryD %>],
  ['S', <%: ViewBag.QueryS %>],
  ['Sh', <%: ViewBag.QuerySh %>],
]);
```

However I would recommend storing the javascript in a seperate `.js` file, and applying the values to relevant HTML data attributes and calling them from there.

```
<div class="google_data_table" data-queryi="<%: ViewBag.QueryI %>" data-queryd="<%: ViewBag.QueryD %>" data-querys="<%: ViewBag.QueryS %>" data-querysh="<%: ViewBag.QuerySh %>">
  //Google data table here
</div>
```

Then using raw javascript, or a js library (I've used jQuery in the example below), get these values in the javascript file and apply them appropriately:

```
var $googledatatable = $(".google_data_table");
var queryI = $googledatatable.data("queryi");
var queryD = $googledatatable.data("queryd");
var queryS = $googledatatable.data("querys");
var querySh = $googledatatable.data("querysh");

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
data.addRows([
  ['I', queryI],
  ['D', queryD],
  ['S', queryS],
  ['Sh', querySh],
]);
```

This is neater and will allow you to reuse the javascript logic for other data tables you may have throughout your application.